# In Django, how can we stop losing the details filled in the form, if it fails validation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am using the [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) for user registration in my Django web app. When the user **fills in the detail** (username, password, confirm_password) **and submits**, then if the form **fails validation** (maybe because username already exists or password don't match or password is too short) then the user is **redirected back to the register** page.

Now my problem is that when he is redirected back to the register page, the form is blank again, i.e. he has to start all over again, which is not a good user experience because his form might fail one or more times.

**I want that if the form fails validation and when he is redirected to the registration form, he should see his previously filled in details** so that he can just correct the field which is causing the error and move on. Is there any way the data can be retained?

Here is my code of the register function in **views.py**:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # some code
            return redirect('login')

        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("register"))

    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html')
```

my register.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text" class="..." style="...">
    <input name="password1" type="password" class="..." style="...">
    <input name="password2" type="password" class="..." style="...">
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

**Edit:**
**I have not passed the form in context to the template, so that I can control the `CSS` of my input fields, which I am not sure how to do otherwise without creating `forms.py` file separately.**

If it's not possible to retain details in the form, then what should I do to at least improve the present situation?

Comment: You are not passing the form in the context? are you manually rendering the form inputs then?

Comment: Pass the form in the context to the template and render via the form object in the template.[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-template) is how you render forms in the html, you can further render the fields manually just read the documentation in this link. I have shown how to pass the form to the context in my answer below.

Comment: yes I am not passing the form in the context, this is my HTML form in the register page: `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">{% csrf_token %} <input fields> </form>`

Comment: Look into using [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) to control your css from the html. I'll make an edit to my answer and give an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of return redirect just render the response with the form object again:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # some code
            return redirect('login')
        messages.error(request, form.errors)

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

In the template since you want to control css use [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/):

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_field form.username class="..." style="..." %}
    {% render_field form.password1 class="..." style="..." %}
    {% render_field form.password2 class="..." style="..." %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

The load widget tweaks must be at the top of the html file like all load tags.

Comment: I have edited my question to add why I have not passed the form in context. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
def register(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            # some code
            return redirect('login')
        else:
           context['form'] = form
           messages.error(request, form.errors)

    context['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

it should work

Comment: please see my question edit, I am not passing the form in the context to the template

Comment: In that case you have  to extract the value of form from the post request and pass it to the form by adding attribute value in the input fields.